# I need my java.js file to reference other .js files

Tags: javascript, html

Initially my HTML file contained all javascript but I've tried to push it into it's own seperate java.js file and then reference it from the HTML. The current java.js requires the code from "jquery-csv.js" and "jquery-1.8.2.js" but since I've moved the javascript into it's own file, it no longer works. I assume this is because the java.js no longer has access to the other .js files.

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-csv.js"></script>
<Script src="Java.js"></script>
```

How would I be able to make it so the java.js file can reference and call the other .js files to ensure the code works?

Comment: I would recommend using  some module bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to solve dependancies

Comment: Does your file actually contain those `<script>` tags like that? HTML tags don't work inside JavaScript source files; you'd have to use something like "requirejs" to load the other sources.